# Inner join within one table

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, postgis, self-join

I have a problem I have tried to work out, but I feel stuck now and hope someone want to help.

I have 2 tables: 
parking_list (list of parking spaces and their attributes) 
area_zone (parking zones)

I wish my result too look like this:

```
area_number     total     sum_hcp
1               20          2
2               45          5
3               30          5
```

I can generate the sum of total parking spaces within each area such:

```
SELECT area.area_number,
      sum(parking.parking_spaces) AS total_sum
FROM my_schema.parking_list parking,
     my_schema.area_zones area
WHERE st_intersects(area.geom, parking.geom)
GROUP BY area.area_number
```

And the sum of hcp parking withing each area

```
SELECT area.area_number,
       sum(parking.parking_spaces) AS sum
FROM my_schema.parking_list parking,
     my_schema.area_zones area
WHERE st_intersects(area.geom, parking.geom) AND parking.hcp = 't' and parking.free = 't'
GROUP BY area.area_number as hcp_parking
```

But I need to join them so i can use it in a view. I have tried a couple of different ways without luck

Here is one example

```
SELECT area.area_number,
       sum(parking.parking_spaces) total_sum
FROM (
   my_schema.parking_list AS parking, my_schema.area_zones AS area
   WHERE st_intersects(area.geom, parking.geom)
) AS total
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT sum(parking.parking_spaces) AS sum_hcp
  FROM my_schema.parking_list AS parking2, my_schema.area_zones AS area2
  WHERE st_intersects(area.geom, parking.geom) AND parking.hcp = 't' and parking.free = 't'
) AS sum_hcp ON total.area_number = sum_hcp.area_number
GROUP BY area.area_number
```

Could someone please lead me in the right direction for what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get both values in a single query by using a conditional expression together with the aggregate sum function:

```
SELECT 
  area.area_number,
  sum(parking.parking_spaces) AS total_sum
  sum(case when parking.hcp = 't' and parking.free = 't' 
           then parking.parking_spaces else 0 end
  ) as sum_hcp
FROM my_schema.parking_list parking,
     my_schema.area_zones area
WHERE st_intersects(area.geom, parking.geom) 
GROUP BY area.area_number;
```

If you want to use a joined derived table instead you do it like below, although the former query should work and perform a lot better:

```
SELECT area.area_number,
      sum(parking.parking_spaces) AS total_sum
      sum(coalesce(hcp_parking.parking_spaces,0)) as sum_hcp
FROM my_schema.parking_list parking,
     my_schema.area_zones area
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT area.area_number,
         parking.parking_spaces
    FROM my_schema.parking_list parking,
         my_schema.area_zones area
    WHERE st_intersects(area.geom, parking.geom) AND parking.hcp = 't' and parking.free = 't'
) hcp_parking ON area.area_number = hcp_parking.area_number
WHERE st_intersects(area.geom, parking.geom)
GROUP BY area.area_number;
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback! i did  not think of using case when inside a function.
When I run it it is complaining schema does not exist.
In the FROM statement have I writter my.schema.parking_list, my_schema.area_zones. I find it very strange as both tables are in the from clause. Any idea of why that is?

Comment: @geogrow I had accidentally written `my_schema_parking_list` where I guess it should have been `my_schema.parking_list` and in your comment you use `my.schema.parking_list` with a dot after my instead of a _ . Double check the from clauses.

Comment: Oh yeah the dot got sneaked its way into my comment too at one place. I understood that it should be my_schema.parking_list, that is how I run the query when it is complaining that the schema does not exist. I appreciate your time, thanks

Comment: @geogrow Are you sure the schema actually exists in the database you are executing the query in?